# How to send email with line break?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail to send emails. So I've got a textArea where customers can compose their messages and send them to me on button press. During my testing I realize that when I press "Enter"/"Return" key inside my textArea it breaks my text but when I check mail box it just one line text!

How to do it?

Please help me guys!

I' using this code for now and it seems working:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="Message" onkeypress="BreakLine();"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function BreakLine() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key == 13) {
    document.getElementById("Message").value = document.getElementById("Message").value + "<br/>";
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I taped something inside textArea it prints `"<br/>"` along with the rest text as well but when I receive email its fine I can see breaks in the text like it suppose to be! But how to get rid of `"<br/>"` inside textArea?

I found this example for outlook (which one I'm using) as well and it uses `"\r\n"` instead of `"<br/>"` but it doesn't work for me!

P.S. I know above example will work only for IE but don't worry about it for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you debug your code and see what string was being passed from the textArea to your code?
By the way you can make your javascript cross-browser compatible:

```
function BreakLine() {
    var key = event.which || event.charCode || event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key == 13) {
    document.getElementById("Message").value = document.getElementById("Message").value + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

If the above line that gets the key does not work, you could always use jquery's "which" function to get the key code no matter what browser it is.

**Edit:**
You can combine the `<br>` and the text in your text area and save this value in a hidden field on your page, instead of appending and showing it in your textarea. Then when the message is to be sent, you can get the message text with appended `<br>`s from this hidden field and send it. This way there will be no annoying `<br>`s in the text area plus your messages will be multi-line as you want.

Comment: Ok. Where does it print <br> and where does it show line break? When user hits ENTER, he sees the added <br> in the text area and when the message is sent display is okay, right? No <br>s, only new lines on the received message. Do I get it right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="Message" onkeypress="BreakLine();"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BreakLine() {
        var key = window.event.keyCode;
        // If the user has pressed enter
        if (key == 13) {
            document.getElementById("Message").value = document.getElementById("Message").value +"\n";
            window.event.preventDefault();
        }
console.log(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Message").value));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me :( The problem might be that I'm using Outlook as a mailbox, but I tired even \r\n but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If the message is `text/plain`, then using `\r\n` should work. Instead, if the message type is `text\html`, use then use `<p/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it on my own, so on "Send Email" button click it checks first does text contain /n (break) if "yes" it adds line into array cell (**lines**). So every line are kept separately. And after that I add every line to hidden textArea value and add `<br/>` in the end of each line.

Text Areas:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
<textarea id="HiddenMessage" name="HiddenMessage" style="display:none;"></textarea>
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" id="SendEmail" value="Send Email" onclick="BreakLine();">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BreakLine() {
    var lines = $('#Message').val().split('\n');

    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("HiddenMessage").value = document.getElementById("HiddenMessage").value + lines[i] + "<br/>";
        }   
    }
</script>
```